# Measure of Public Transportation Efficiency (Consumer side)

Tags: econometrics, transportation

I'm looking for data on public transportation efficiency for consumers by city or county. In some places you can get across town in under 20min and in other places it takes 2hrs and this likely has important economic consequences. This seems like it would be a 1-day Google developer project and something one person could do with a Google maps/directions API and a good computer, so I'm wondering if its out there already: a measure of time to distance traveled on public transit within each US city or county.